# Redis/Redisson LocalCachedMap - How does TTL/Eviction work?

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am trying to implement an RLocalCachedMap in my app.  While experimenting I was creating a LocalCachedMap and was setting an evictionPolicy and TTL in the LocalCachedMapOptions.  I was expecting that any entry added to the map would expire after the max TTL had passed, but I learned that was not the case.  I later learned that such functionality is only available in RedissonPRO which I am not using.

Now I am wondering, if setting the EvictionPolicy and TTL in the LocalCachedMapOptions will actually do anything at all?  Does the entry have an expiration time on the Redis server?  If so, can I configure Redis to clear out expired entries since Redisson seems to ignore the TTL?

Is there any way to use the RLocalCachedMap and have entries expire after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 2):

EvictionPolicy and TimeToLive are applied to RLocalCachedMap instance if they defined.

> if setting the EvictionPolicy and TTL in the LocalCachedMapOptions will actually do anything at all? Does the entry have an expiration time on the Redis server?

Only entry stored in local cache get this ttl and not entry stored in Redis.

> If so, can I configure Redis to clear out expired entries since Redisson seems to ignore the TTL?

to apply ttl for Redis you need to use RLocalCachedMapCache (part of Redisson PRO) or RMapCache object (without local cache)

Comment: TTL does not seem to work locally either.

Comment: Tried also with `RMapCache<String, String> cache = redissonClient.getMapCache(CACHE_NAME, options);`. Same result, entries seem to stay forever in the map even though I've set `timeToLive` to 1 sec in options.

Comment: Can you open the issue on github with code example to reproduce it?

Comment: We are using the free open source version. I noticed that according to this TTL does not work with that (`getLocalCachedMap()`) : https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/7.-distributed-collections#71-map

We'd like to use the local map for performance.

Comment: Or should I use `RLocalCachedMap#getCachedMap`? Based on Javadoc I don't understand how it differs from calling `RLocalCachedMap` directly.

Comment: Based on my testing using `RLocalCachedMap#getCachedMap` makes TTL work.